# SQL Server Dynamic Where Clause - combination of wildcard, multiple values or 1 value

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, where-clause

I created a stored proc with a parameter (@iParam) where user will enter up to a maximum 10 "values". The "values" that user will enter will be a ***combination*** and/or ***ALL of the three types***:

1. Using Wild Card - i.e. ABC%
2. Multiple Exact Values - i.e. BIRD, CAT, DOG
3. 1 Exact Value - i.e. WOLF

The question now is, in my WHERE clause, how do I make it dynamic to switch and/or use the ***LIKE***, ***=***, ***IN*** operator depending on user's entered "values"? i.e:

1. Using Wild Card - WHERE clause will need to use ***LIKE*** operator
2. Multiple Exact Values - WHERE clause will need to use ***IN*** operator
3. 1 Exact Value - WHERE clause just need to use ***=*** operator

Example 1: If user were to input '%TEXT%' and USA as the values, the WHERE clause needs to know that it'll use **LIKE** and **=** operator

Example 2: If user were to input 'STRING%', JOHN, JANE, MARY as the values, the WHERE clause needs to know that it'll use **LIKE** and **IN** operator

Example 3: If user were to input SNOOPY, DOG as the values, the WHERE clause needs to know that it'll use **IN** operator

Comment: `LIKE 'Wolf'` and `= 'Wolf'` are synonyms so assuming that the column vales can't have the characters % or _ in them seems like you just need to split on the delimiter (there are literally 1,000s of dupes for that) and you have your answer.

Comment: @ Lamu thanks for replying. The problem lies in user's input. User can input values using a wildcard, multiple values and/or 1 single value. Thus the question as to know how to make the WHERE clause to be dynamic.

Comment: make your UI more interactive, let users decide whether they want similar results (Like operator) or looking for an exact term (= operator) , or looking for multiple exact terms (In operator). Then use those selections to build your sql dynamically.

Comment: By fixing the application design and making it use a table type parameter.

Comment: Also, @David.L, I would appreciate if you spell my alias correctly. :)

Comment: There's not really much UI in it, since where the values users are inputting is in Excel's cells. And so far, I've put 10 cells where users can do their inputs.

Comment: Just split your string, create '(like ...)' from every part, aggregate all parts with 'or' and you are almost done :)